# type object argument after ** must be a mapping, not str

Tags: python

I wanna get json from the site and change it into python object. 
I wrote this code but it shows me this error:

```
    ----- line 25, in <module>
    meme_list.append(meme(**u))
TypeError: type object argument after ** must be a mapping, not str
```

here is my code:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes'
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
with open('meme_imgflip.json', 'wb') as outf:
    outf.write(response.content)

class meme:
    def __init__(self, name, url, id):
        self.name = name
        self.url = url
        self.id = id
    @staticmethod
    def from_json(meme_string):
        return meme(**json_dict)
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<meme {self.id}>'

meme_list = []
with open('meme_imgflip.json', 'r') as json_file:
    meme_data = json.loads(json_file.read())
    for u in meme_data:
        meme_list.append(meme(**u))
print (meme_list)
```

Comment: The error seems pretty clear, `u` is apparently a `str`, not a mapping (i.e. `dict`) as you apparently expected.

Comment: Also, the name `json_dict` used in `from_json` is never defined anywhere.

Comment: Unrelated tip: you can use `json.load(json_file)` instead of `json.loads(json_file.read())`

Comment: What does `print(meme_data)` look like?

Comment: It probably needs `json_dict = json.loads(meme_string)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The API you're calling returns a dictionary, not a list. The list of memes is in `meme_data['data']['memes']`. So the loop should be:

```
for u in meme_data['data']['memes']:
    meme_list.append(meme(**u))
```

Answer (score 0):

`meme_data` contains a dict, so `u` gets assigned the *keys* to that dict, which are strings.  It isn't clear what you want instead.

Comment: I suspect he's expecting it to be a list of dicts, not a single dict.